# Symfony2 command change environment

Tags: php, testing, symfony, command, env

I want to set up an order allowing me to make clear: cache test mode, then do a drop database, drop scheama, add scheme, add fixtures in test mode.

```
class BaseCommand extends \Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command {

//put your code here

protected function configure()
{
    $this
            ->setName('mycommand:test')
            ->setDescription('Launch test')
    ;

}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $command_first_migration = $this->getApplication()->find('cache:clear');
    $arguments_first_migration = array(
        'command' => 'cache:clean',
        '--env' => 'test'
    );
    $input_first_migration = new ArrayInput($arguments_first_migration);
    try {

        $returnCode = $command_first_migration->run($input_first_migration, $output);


    } catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\MigrationException $ex) {
        echo "MigrationExcepion !!!! ";
    }
}
```

}

but I have this result :

```
clearing the case for the dev environment with debug true
```

How to pass the test in dev environment?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can't set the --env=test since the Kernel and the environment are already created when you run php app/console mycommand:test.

The only way is to specify the env when you run your command :

```
php app/console mycommand:test --env=test
```

Comment: Thank you. Now, when I use the doctrine:schema:create I have this error : no selected database.

Comment: Can you open a new question for that ? don't forget to approve my answer if it suit you :)

Comment: This is the right answer, very counter-intuitive if following the SF2 doc